# Modifying a keyword search function to either ignore/print NAs or print "verify"

Tags: r, list, na

I am trying to access a public database containing information regarding certain kinds of jobs.

The function I've created is this:

```
onet.sum <- function(x) { 
  obj1 <- as.list(keySearch(x)) # enter self-reported job title into ONET's search engine 
  job.title <- obj1[["title"]][1] # pull best-matching title 
  soc.code <- obj1[["code"]][1] # pull best matching title's SOC code 
  obj4 <- as.data.frame(cbind(job.title,soc.code)) 
  return(obj4) 
}
```

If apply onet.sum to a dataset containing two job titles AND the job titles do not contain spaces, it works:

```
 final_data <- lapply(c("psychologist","socialworker"), onet.sum) %>% 
  bind_rows
```

If I include NAs, then it breaks:

```
 final_data <- lapply(c("psychologist","socialworker", NA), onet.sum) %>% 
  bind_rows
```

Specifically, this error is thrown:
Error in `[.data.frame`(keyOutput, , 1:2) : undefined columns selected.

...which can be traced back to the keySearch() function that is called by my onet.sum() function.

```
keySearch <- 
  function (keyword) {
    output <- getURL(paste("https://services.onetcenter.org/ws/mnm/search?keyword=", 
        keyword, sep = ""), userpwd = paste(get("creds", envir = cacheEnv)[[1]],
        ":", get("creds", envir = cacheEnv)[[2]], sep = ""), 
        httpauth = 1L)
    if (grepl("Authorization Error", output)) {
        message("Your API credentials are invalid. Please enter valid HTTPS credentials using setCreds().")
    }
    else if (grepl("total=\"0\"", output)) {
        message("Your keyword returned no results. Please try another keyword or occupational title.")
    }
    else {
        output <- xmlParse(output)
        keyOutput <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(output, 
            "//career"))
        message("Find a SOC code below and use with socSearch() function to pull job data.")
        return(keyOutput[, 1:2])
    }
}
```

*Questions*

1. How to modify the keySearch() function such that NAs are printed in the keyOutput() object when a row does not contain a job title?
2. There are some job titles that do not return results (e.g., "help desk support specialist" does not generate a result, even when the spaces are ignored). I'm fine printing these as values to be checked because the website I'm working with clearly can generate a result for "help desk support specialist". Ideally, I could debug this issue, but I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package maintainer here. To address these bugs, I made some updates to the dev version on Github, which has also had some other major changes over the years as well, including collapsing multiple functions together. In essence, all the job info functions are collapsed into `jobInfo()` wherein you explicitly indicate what type of info you're searching for, and `keySearch()` and `socSearch()` were collapsed into `jobSearch()` wherein you indicate if your search `type="keyword"` or `type="soc"`. I did my best to avoid breaking changes, so all old functions should still work fine albeit with a message indicating they're technically 'deprecated'.

### Instructions to install dev version:

1. Go to https://github.com/eknud/ONETr
2. Click the green button in the top right 'Code' and 'Download ZIP'.
3. Unzip the file.
4. Run command `devtools::install("path/to/unzipped_folder")` in R. You should now be set up to run the dev functions.

### Updated onet.sum function and test code

```
onet.sum <- function(x) {
    obj1 <- as.list(jobSearch(x, type = "keyword"))
    job.title <- obj1[["title"]][1] # pull best-matching title
    soc.code <- obj1[["code"]][1] # pull best matching title's SOC code
    obj4 <- as.data.frame(cbind(job.title,soc.code))
    return(obj4)
}

# now test it
library(ONETr)
library(tidyverse)

setCreds("user","pass")

final_data <- lapply(c("psychologist","social worker",NA), onet.sum) %>% bind_rows
```

Comment: It works! A few caveats with some live data.

I had a few self-reported job titles that didn't work, but out of a dataset of >700, that's a good thing. 

Also, I learned that a list needs to be passed through the ones.sum() function. Otherwise, looks good.